# QEMU virtual networking NAT

Tags: virtualization, iptables, qemu

I'm trying to set up a virtual network as described [here](http://qemu-buch.de/cgi-bin/moin.cgi/QemuAndTuntap#head-83db43940577fa8a6f4cdb79693329be1175ba1a). These are my steps:

```
ifup eth0 # uses DHCP
brctl addbr br0
ifconfig br0 up 192.168.0.1
kvm ... -device e1000,netdev=tap0 -netdev type=tap,id=tap0,sccript=/etc/qemu-ifup
```

where qemu-ifup does

```
ifconfig tap0 0.0.0.0 promisc up
brctl addif br0 tap0
```

And finally, inside the vm,

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.2
route add default gw 192.168.0.1
```

This allows me to ping 192.168.0.1 and 10.42.42.127 (the host's IPs) from inside the guest, and the guest from inside the host.

However, I cannot ping a guest from inside another guest, nor any other IP outside the host (10.42.42.1, or 8.8.8.8, for example).

How should I set this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two question:

1) Have you allowed a forwarding between br0 and eth0? You can check it via this command:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

If you get a "0", you must correct it to "1":

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

You can allow it in the /etc/sysctl.conf permanently.

2) You have to have a NAT settings via iptables, for example somethink like:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```